# PostgreSQL create jdbc_fdw extension fails

Tags: java, postgresql

My db version is 9.3

I want to create the jdbc_fdw extension,I got the error message:

```
could not load library "/opt/PostgresPlus/9.3AS/lib/jdbc_fdw.so": libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had use ldd to check jdbc_fdw.so:

```
ldd /opt/PostgresPlus/9.3AS/lib/jdbc_fdw.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbed82000)
    libjvm.so => /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so (0x00007f79fe1f7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f79fde51000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f79fdbcd000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f79fd9c9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f79fd7ab000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000365fc00000)
```

But I still can't create this extension.

My .bash_profile like below:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/PostgresPlus/9.3AS/bin
PGDATA=/bin:/opt/PostgresPlus/9.3AS/data
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server
export PATH
export PGDATA
export JAVA_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to make sure the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the **postgres** (Linux) user is correct as the libraries will be loaded by that user (assuming the Postgres service is started using that user)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Running `ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so /lib64/libjvm.so`
fixed the problem for me.